# Without using the fundamental theorem of homomorphisms show $G/(\ker(f)) \equiv H$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_9$, $H=\mathbb{Z}_3$, and $f(n)=n \mod 3$.

1. Show $f:G \to H$ is well defined.
2. Show $f:G \to H$ is an onto homomorphism.
3. Without using Theorem 8.13 show $G/(\ker(f)) \equiv H$.

$\textbf{Part a:}$
A map is well-defined if it satisfy the following properties:

1. Every element in the domain maps to an element in the codomain $$x
       \in G \Rightarrow f(x) \in H$$
2. If $f(n)=n \mod 3$ and $f(m)=m \mod 3$, then $f(n)+f(m)=n+m \mod 3$.

$\textbf{Proof of Property 1:}$
Since the set of $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is small enough we can list all the mappings of $f$. So we have

1. $f(0)=f(3)=f(6)=0 \mod 3$
2. $f(1)=f(4)=f(7)=1 \mod 3$
3. $f(2)=f(5)=f(8)=2 \mod 3$

Since all the outputs of $f$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}_3$, we can say that $f$ is well-defined.

$\textbf{Proof of Property 2:}$
Assume that $f(n)=n \mod 3$ and $f(m)=m \mod 3$. By definition,
$$f(n)=n \mod 3  k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}  \,f(n)=n+3k_1 $$
$$f(m)=m \mod 3  k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}  \,f(m)=m+3k_2 $$

We add both equations and we obtain $$f(n)+f(m)=n+m+3k_1+3k_2=n+m+3(k_1+k_2)$$  If we let $k=k_1+k_2$ then we have by definition of mod $f(n)+f(m)=n+m \mod 3$.

Hence $f$ is well-defined.

$\textbf{Part b:}$ We need to show that $f$ is (1) a homomorphism and (2) an onto function. First we will show that $f$ is a homomorphism.

We know that $G$ and $H$ are both groups. A homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is a map $f:G \to H$ such that for all $x,y \in G$, we have $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. So, $$f(x)f(y)=(x \mod 3)(y \mod 3)=(xy) \mod 3=f(xy)$$ Hence f is a homomorphism.

Next, we need to show that this homomorphism is onto (i.e. a surjective homomorphism). A surjective function is one for which the entire codomain is spanned by the function's values. That is, the range of the function is the codomain. (i.e. $\forall y \in H, \exists x \in G \,such \,that \,h(x) = y$) From the proof of f being well-defined. We can see that each y value, elements of $\mathbb{Z}^3=\{0,1,2\}$ there exists at least one value from G. Hence $f$ is onto.

In all, f is an onto homomorphism.

$\textbf{Part c:}$

Theorem 8.13 states Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. Then

1. $\ker \phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$;
2. $\operatorname{im} \phi$ is a subgroup of $H$; and
3. $G/ \ker \phi \equiv \operatorname{im} \phi$

How would I proof this without the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that :

- $f:G\rightarrow H$ gives a homomorphism $\bar{f} : G/Ker(f)\rightarrow H$.
- Prove that this is injective. (Is it necessary to prove again??)
- Probe that this map is surjective.

Then you are done...

For that homomorphism...

$$\bar{f}(\overline{ab})=f(ab)=f(a)f(b)=\bar{f}(\bar{a})\bar{f}(\bar{b})$$

Comment: How should we define $\bar{f} explictly?

Comment: you do not have to define anything explicitly... If you want you can see that as $\bar{f}(xKer(f))=f(x)$..

Comment: Can you provide a formal proof?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown :  I can provide but before that tell me what is wrong with the hints that are given so far...?

Comment: I am stuck with the proof of $\bar{f}$ is a homomorphism

Comment: All you have to prove is $\bar{f}(ab \mod Ker(f))=\bar{f}(a\mod Ker(f))\bar{f}(b\mod Ker(f))$... What is $\bar{f}(ab\mod Ker(f))$??

Comment: That is where I am not sure the notation and working of $\bar{f}$ is what is trowing me off

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : See my edit...